# Dealing with removed APIs while upgrading Kubernetes version on AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

```
>>> Deprecated APIs removed in 1.25 <<<
KIND NAMESPACE NAME API_VERSION REPLACE_WITH (SINCE)
PodSecurityPolicy kube-prometheus-stack-alertmanager policy/v1beta1 (1.21.0)
PodSecurityPolicy kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics policy/v1beta1 (1.21.0)
PodSecurityPolicy kube-prometheus-stack-operator policy/v1beta1 (1.21.0)
PodSecurityPolicy kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus policy/v1beta1 (1.21.0)
PodSecurityPolicy monitoring kube-prometheus-stack-grafana policy/v1beta1 (1.21.0)
PodSecurityPolicy monitoring kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-test policy/v1beta1 (1.21.0)
PodSecurityPolicy monitoring kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter policy/v1beta1 (1.21.0)`
```

We are trying to upgrade the kubernetes version to 1.25.6. Currently we are using 1.24.6 and 1.24.10. Before upgrading when I ran kubent in my AKS cluster checking for the deprecated APIs, I got that these APIs are removed in 1.25. What is the solution for this (for the deprecated or removed APIs)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using PSP then remove them and proceed with the K8S upgrade, otherwise familiarise yourself with what they do and see if this creates a gap for you.

> The pod security policy feature will be deprecated starting with
> Kubernetes version 1.21 and will be removed in version 1.25.
>
> The AKS API will mark the pod security policy as Deprecated on
> 06-01-2023 and remove it in version 1.25. We recommend you migrate to
> pod security admission controller before the deprecation deadline to
> stay within Azure support.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-pod-security-policies

Answer (score -1):

the solution is to upgrade your resources to a newer api version